# Navigating in menu with keybord keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a menu list with links that I want to navigate with the up and down arrow keys. The right arrow key indicates "enter" and the link and left key on a previous page. Also the on-hovered link must be stick on the first position. If I am on Line 3 it must focus it on top on the fist line.

```
<a href="test1.php">Line 1</a><br>
<a href="test2.php">Line 2</a><br>
<a href="test3.php">Line 3</a><br>
<a href="test4.php">Line 4</a><br>
<a href="test5.php">Line 5</a><br>
```

My code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tv6xV/

Comment: you can see if you type arrow key down first the scrollbar scrolls down i want a focus on the first line if i press to next line it must be on top

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` will stop the default behaviour (the scroll you're mentioning, for instance). Is that the problem you're trying to solve?